# How to properly initialize geofence list in Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-geofence

I'm trying to get geofences working on Android Studio. When debugging, I receive "No geofence has been added to this request."

the code below worked for someone else. I have also tried 
`lateinit var geofencelist : ArrrayList<Geofence>` however the error message returns geofencelist not properly initialized.

```
> lateinit var geofencelist : MutableList<Geofence>
```

have tried MutableList as well as lateinit and in style below

```
> private var geofencelist : ArrayList<Geofence>? = null 
> 
> //geofence builder successful geofencelist?.add(geofence) 
> 
> Log.e("D", geofencelist?.count().toString())
```

output received:

> E/D: null Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No geofence
>   has been added to this request.

TYIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geofencelist?.add(geofence)` does nothing if you haven't set `geofencelist` to something non-null, that's the [point of `?.`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls).

It certainly doesn't seem like you should be doing something tricky, since list initialization is trivial; just

```
val geofencelist = mutableListOf<Geofence>
```

then `geofencelist.add(geofence)` where you had `?.add`.